# Need assistnce with Jquery ajax toggle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So i have a like button for my comment's, works fine but I need a little enhancement on it. Here's the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".voteMe").click(function() {
        var voteId = this.id;                        
        var all_id = voteId.split(' ');
        var cid = voteId.split('_');
        var id_values = all_id[1].split('_');
        var upOrDown = id_values[0];
        var user_id = id_values[1];
        var topic_id = id_values[2];
        var uri = "http://localhost/forum/topic/votes/" + cid[0] + '/' + upOrDown + '/' + user_id + '/' +topic_id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: uri,                                
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){                
                try{
                    if(response === 'true'){    
                        var newValue = parseInt($("#"+all_id[0]+'_result').text()) + 1;
                        $("#"+all_id[0]+'_result').html(newValue);
                    }else{
                         alert("unable to update");
                    }
                }catch(e) {
                    alert('Exception while request..');
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
         });
      });
  });
</script>
```

So what I want is when the like button is click by a user it should be disabled and when the dislike button is clicked by the same user -1 would be subtracted from the like button and then the like button would be enabled and the dislike disabled.

Here's the html code for the like and dislike. I know this is too much to ask, I'd be really grateful if this is done.

```
<div class="likeblock pull-left">                                
    <a id="<?= $comment->id ?>_upvote up_<?= $comment->user_id?>_<?= $comment->topic_id?>" class="up voteMe">
         <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
         <span id="<?= $comment->id ?>_upvote_result" ><?=$comment->up_vote_count?></span>
    </a>
    <a id="<?= $comment->id ?>_downvote down_<?= $comment->user_id?>_<?= $comment->topic_id?>" class="down voteMe">
         <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>
         <span id="<?= $comment->id ?>_downvote_result" ><?=$comment->down_vote_count?></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think following section needs focus, both if and else seems to simlar

```
                    if(response === 'true'){    
                        var newValue = parseInt($("#"+all_id[0]+'_result').text()) + 1;
                        $("#"+all_id[0]+'_result').html(newValue);
                    }else{
                        var newValue = parseInt($("#"+all_id[0]+'_result').text()) + 1;
                        $("#"+all_id[0]+'_result').html(newValue);
                    }
```

Comment: I made little changes in my model so the else block now looks like this else{ alert("Unable to update"); }

Comment: Also do add condition to check whether it is up vote or down vote and update value of span accordingly in response === true block